# python sub command cog file

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello everything working fine with my sub command in main page. But if i move commands to cog file sub commands not works i added `self, ctx` and also `self.bot` but still its not working any idea at which place i doing wrong.

```
@commands.group(pass_context=True)
async def first(self, ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await self.bot.say("Ping 1")

@first.group(pass_context=True)
async def second(self, ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is second:
        await self.bot.say("Ping 2")

@second.command(pass_context=True)
async def third(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("Ping 3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`second` is not defined when the body of `second` is evaluated.  Furthermore, `invoked_subcommand` will always be `second` here, even if you also invoke `third`.

You should pass the [`invoke_without_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Group.invoke_without_command) property to your `group` decorators instead.

```
@commands.group(pass_context=True, invoke_without_command=True)
async def first(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("Ping 1")

@first.group(pass_context=True, invoke_without_command=True)
async def second(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("Ping 2")

@second.command(pass_context=True)
async def third(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("Ping 3")
```

Edit:

On reflection, this might have been over-thinking it.  You just need to resolve `second` through the class it's a method of:

```
class MyCog:    
    @commands.group(pass_context=True)
    async def first(self, ctx):
        if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
            await self.bot.say("Ping 1")

    @first.group(pass_context=True)
    async def second(self, ctx):
        if ctx.invoked_subcommand is MyCog.second:  # Possibly self.second instead, but I'm not sure.  
            await self.bot.say("Ping 2")

    @second.command(pass_context=True)
    async def third(self, ctx):
        await self.bot.say("Ping 3")
```

Comment: First code is working fine for me so what is d difference and should i use first code or second code.

Comment: They should be functionally identical. It just depends which style you like better.  I prefer the first option.